# how can I load a file while $SAFE = 1

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to get the following to work

```
filename = File.expand_path("./script")
filename.taint
$SAFE = 1
load(filename)
```

From what I understand this should work based on the ruby documentation. However I receive

```
 `load': Insecure operation - load (SecurityError)
```

I am obviously missing something but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't pay enough attention to the documentation

```
filename = File.expand_path("./script.rb")
puts filename.untaint
$SAFE = 1
load(filename)
```